# Present subjunctive in vos form

Tags: diferencias-regionales, voseo, subjuntivo, verbos, conjugación

What is the rule for conjugating verbs in the vos form in the present subjunctive? If it varies by region, what are the differences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the conjugation for the "vos" pronoun in forms beyond the present indicative?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20837/how-is-the-conjugation-for-the-vos-pronoun-in-forms-beyond-the-present-indicat)

Comment: @ukemi this question is from 2011 and the other is from 2017. If something is duplicated then that's the other question and again I don't think it makes sense to close old questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* explains that there are [two major types of *voseo*](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=voseo):

1. **Reverential *voseo***: archaic and ceremonial usage. Spanish speakers in the Americas are familiar with this type of *voseo* from historic and religious texts.
2. **American dialectal *voseo***: the different forms of *voseo* from the Spanish dialects of the Americas.

The *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* provides a detailed explanation of the [regional variants](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=voseo#23) (in Spanish) and includes a [*voseo* conjugation table](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=voseo#243d) by country and tense for the verbs *cantar*, *comer*, and *vivir* . Wikipedia explains the regional differences in the use of [voseo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo#Subjunctive) under the present subjunctive for the irregular verbs *dormir* and *mentir*:

- **Ríoplatense region (Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay), informal**: *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás*
- **Ríoplatense region (Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay), formal**: *cantes*, *comas*, *vivas*, *duermas*, *mientas*
- **Chile, Southern Perú (especially Arequipa), Northwestern Argentina**: *cantí(s)*, *comái(s)*, *vivái(s)*, *durmái(s)*, *mintái(s)*
- **Western and Southern Bolivia (*colla* zone)**: *cantes*, *comas*, *vivas*, *duermas*, *mientas*
- **Northern and Eastern Bolivia (*camba* zone)**: *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás*
- **Northern Ecuadorian Coast (Esmeraldas)**: *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás*
- **Ecuadorian Sierra (Andes), parts of Northern Peru**: *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás* or *cantes*, *comas*, *vivas*, *duermas*, *mientas*
- **Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Colombia (*paisa* and *valluno* dialects, Pacific coast), Venezuela (Andes)**: *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás*
- **Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras**: *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás* or *cantes*, *comas*, *vivas*, *duermas*, *mientas*
- **Panama (Azuero), Venezuela (Zulia), reverential**: *canteís*, *comáis*, *viváis*, *durmáis*, *mintáis*
- **Mexico (Chiapas and Tabasco)** (rare): *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás*
- **Eastern Cuba** (rare): *cantés*, *comás*, *vivás*, *durmás*, *mintás*

Comment: Great find! My biggest confusion though is about irregular verbs, and those don't seem to be addressed in that list.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [voseo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo#Subjunctive) contains examples for the irregular verbs _dormir_ and _mentir_. I added those examples to the answer. Were you interested in the conjugation of another irregular verb?

Comment: I'd say rare for the ecuadorean coast too... I lived there 7 years.

Comment: @Joze: I clarified in the answer that _voseo_ is predominant on the Northern Ecuadorian coast (Esmeraldas), according to the [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=voseo#234a). It seems like there is a link between _voseo_ in Esmeraldas and _voseo_ in the Colombian Pacific coast.

Comment: @JaimeSoto: Now that you edited it with Esmeraldas I agree!! :-)

Comment: @JaimeSoto: Ah that's helpful. It's a general rule for the subjunctive vos form that I'm looking for. For example, how do you know it's mintás instead of mentás or mientás? It seems like these cases are not quite regular, but not quite fully irregular :)

Comment: @jrdioko. If you know the vosotros forms, just remove the "i". So, from "(vosotros) mintáis", you get "(vos) mintás"; from (vosotros) "durmáis", you get "(vos) durmás" and so on. It almost always works. Of course you have to know the vosotros forms. And in some countries, these forms are not unheard of at all, but are considered substandard and uneducated. Here in Argentina, for example, the educated standard for  subjunctive is using the same conjugation for vos and tú, although the pronoun itself (tú) is never used. So you'd say "vos no digas nada", but not "vos no digás nada".

Answer (score 1):

It is generally conjugated as the second person, or like the 'vosotros' conjugation (second plural), but wihout the last i.

> La ley requiere que (vos) *tengas* 18 años para votar.

Second person: (tu) tengas
Second plural: (vosotros) tengáis

> Te dije que (vos) lo *pusieras* sobre la mesa.

Second person: (tu) pusieras
Second plural: (vosotros) pusierais

Comment: I've never seen vosotros téngais or pusiérais, only [tengáis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teng%C3%A1is) or [pusierais](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pusierais).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any differences between the `vos` and `tú` forms in the present subjunctive. Any irregularity comes from the `yo` stem.

After that, the `vos` conjugation has an "s" just like the `tú` conjugation.

Comment: Jaime Soto's answer above seems to indicate this isn't true in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed by Alpha, the conjugation is related to the second plural ('vosotros') (*). The general rule is to trim the last 'i'

**tú comes**  (you eat) (second singular, standard form)

**vosotros coméis**  (you eat) (second plural)

**vos comés**  (you eat) (second singular, with 'voseo')

In the imperative, the final 'd' is suppresed

**eh, tú, espera**  (hey, you, wait)

**eh, vosotros, esperad**

**eh, vos, esperá**

And, as always, there are some irregularities, eg

" tú, dime" "vosotros, decidme"  "vos, decime" (hey, you, tell me)

(*) To make things more confusing, 'vosotros' is not much used in some regions with 'voseo', as Argentina; here, we mostly use 'ustedes' as second plural pronoun, plural form of 'usted' (respectful second person). Both 'usted'/'ustedes' are conjugated as third person.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of voseo. I was actually looking for rules for the *present subjunctive* (e.g. "Quiero que vos (venir) conmigo.")

Comment: @jrdioko: _venir_ would be conjugated as _vos vengás_, _vos vengas_, _vos vengái_, or _vos vengáis_ depending on the region. See [my answer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/822/128).