# How is the conjugation for the "vos" pronoun in forms beyond the present indicative?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugación, voseo

How is **vos** (the Argentine pronoun) conjugated in forms beyond the present indicative? Would it be the same as the **vosotros** forms, except that the *i* is omitted?

For example:

> Vos comprastes; Vos bebistes; Vos vivistes

And if this is the case, does this apply to all other tenses/aspects/moods and their conjugations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Argentina, the pronoun is normally conjugated identically to the *tú* form in all forms except for the present indicative (*-ás*, *-és*, *-ís*) and the imperative (*-á*, *-é*, *-í*), although it may popularly used with other conjugations.

Note that the pronoun is not exclusive to Argentina by any means, and you can find quite a few different forms depending on where you are at.  Chile tends to have the most unique forms, some places are more conservative (Venezuela, Cuba) and retain forms that perfectly coincide with the *vos reverencial* (which is the same as modern day *vosotros/as* in Spain and Equatorial Guinea), and all feature some degree of overlap between *tú* and *vos* forms.

```
Present indicative
  -ás, -és, ís
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Bolivia, Ecuador, Colombia, Venezuela
     Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Mexico
  -ái, -í, -í
     Chile
  -áis, ís, ís
     Chile, Ecuador
  -áis, -éis, ís
     Bolivia, Venezuela, Panama
  -ái, éi, ís
     Panama, Cuba

Imperfect indicative
  -abas, -ías, -ías
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Perú, Bolivia, Ecuador, Colombia, Venezuela,
     Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Panama, Mexico,
     Cuba
  -abai(s), -íai(s), -íai(s)
     Chile

Simple preterite perfect indicative
  -aste, -iste, -iste
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Chile, Bolivia, Ecuador, Colombia, Venezuela,
     Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Costa Rica, Panama, Cuba
  -astes, -istes, -istes
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Chile, Perú, Colombia, Venezuela,
     Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Nicaragua, Mexico
  -ates, -ites, -ites
     Colombia, Venezuela

Future indicative
  -ás, -ás, -ás
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Bolivia, Colombia, Ecuador, Venezuela, 
     Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Panama
  -ís, -ís, -ís
     Chile, Ecuador
  -í, -í, -í
     Chile
  -ás, -ís, -ís
     Peru 
  -és, -és, -és
     Colombia, Venezuela, Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Mexico
   -éis, -éis, -éis
     Venezuela, Cuba
   -éi, -éi, -éi
     Cuba

Present subjunctive
  -es, -as, -as
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Peru, Bolivia, Ecuador, Venezuela,
     Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Panama, Mexico, Cuba
  -és, -ás, -ás
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Bolivia, Colombia, Guatemala,
     El Salvador, Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica
  -ís, -áis, -áis
     Chile
  -í, -ái, -ái
     Chile

Imperfect subjunctive
  -ras/-ses, -ras/-ses, -ras/-ses
     Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, Bolivia, Ecuador, Colombia, Venezuela,
     Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Panama, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, 
     Mexico, Cuba
  -rai/-sei, -rai/-sei, -rai/-sei
     Chile
  -rais/-seis, -rais/-seis, -rais/-seis
     Chile
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta muy extensa e interesante. La agradezco mucho.

Comment: @K.O'Hara I still need to touch it up a bit , but will finish it in the morning.